# Setting output width with ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, stl

I'd like to display a vector (implemented in my custom `Vector` class) and have the output width of the elements be configurable. I've done this by creating a simple wrapper for the element being displayed which stores the desired width in a static field. I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

```
/** A struct for formatting doubles with a fixed width. */
struct FixedWidthDouble {
  FixedWidthDouble(double x) : x_(x) {}
  double x_;
  static int width_;
};

/** Apply a fixed width manipulator to a double for display. */
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,
    const FixedWidthDouble &fixedWidthDouble) {
  return out << std::setw(fixedWidthDouble.width_) << fixedWidthDouble.x_;
}
```

Here's an example of it being applied:

```
/** Convert a Vector into a stream suitable for display. */
std::ostream& Vector::Print(std::ostream& out, int width) const {
  out << "[" << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed;
  FixedWidthDouble::width_ = width;
  std::copy(begin(), end(), std::ostream_iterator<FixedWidthDouble>(out, " "));
  return out << " ]";
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

**Proposed Solution**

Based on feedback from Begemoth this is the solution I decided to go with. Does this look reasonable?

```
template<int width>
struct FixedWidthDouble {
  FixedWidthDouble(double x) : x_(x) {}
  double x_;
};

/** Apply a fixed width manipulator to a double for display. */
template <int width>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,
    const FixedWidthDouble<width> &fixedWidthDouble) {
  return out << std::setw(width) << fixedWidthDouble.x_;
}

/** Convert a Vector into a stream suitable for display. */
template <int width>
std::ostream& Vector::Print(std::ostream& out) const {
  out << "[" << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed;
  std::copy(begin(), end(),
      std::ostream_iterator<FixedWidthDouble<width> >(out, " "));
  return out << " ]";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are one problem with your approach you make local information global as consequence your `FixedWidthDouble` class is not thread-safe. There is a simple way to solve the problem by turning `width_` into a integral template argument of the class template `template<int width> FixedWidthDouble`.

In C++11 I'd use range-based for:

```
std::ostream& Vector::Print(std::ostream& out, int width) const
{
  out << "[" << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed;
  for (auto& x : *this)
    out << std::setw(width) << x;
  return out << " ]";
}
```

In the old C++98 it is cleaner to use old `for` with iterators.  Also you can create a new iterator type that will set the width:

```
template<typename T, typename CharT = char, typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharT> >
class width_ostream_iterator
  : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
public:
  typedef CharT char_type;
  typedef Traits traits_type;
  typedef std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> ostream_type;

private:
  ostream_type* stream;
  const CharT* separator;
  int width;

public:
  explicit width_ostream_iterator(ostream_type& stm, int width, const CharT* separator = 0)
    : stream(&stm), separator(separator), width(width)
  { }

  width_ostream_iterator& operator=(const T& value)
  {
    *stream << std::setw(width) << value;
    if (separator) *stream << separator;
    return *this;
  }

  width_ostream_iterator& operator*()     { return *this; }
  width_ostream_iterator& operator++()    { return *this; }
  width_ostream_iterator& operator++(int) { return *this; }
};
```

**Update:** Your proposed solution is valid if the width can only be changed at compile time, if you want to change the width at the runtime (e.g. from configuration file or command line arguments) you have to use plain `for` loop or the `width_ostream_iterator` I've provided.  One thing I do not like about the `width_ostream_iterator` — it is definitely a library entity intended to be used in multiple places but it allows you only to change the width of the field and nothing else.  It is too specific for the library (it does not allow an arbitrary manipulator to a stream before outputting a value) it is too complicated for a single use.

And one more note: the `Print` function uses only public interface of the vector (I assume that `begin` and `end` functions are public), so it does not required to be a member function.  Prefer to make such functions free not member.  Why not use member function for all class operations? You can extend the interface of a class without modifying it, e.g. you can have a `Vector` class and stream I/O operations defined in separate headers, you can later add another I/O operations (e.g. for `QDataStream`) in a third header and you will not have to recompile the parts of the program that depend only on the first and second headers.  Your `Print` function can potentially work with any class which looks and behaves like a standard sequence, just like any algorithm from the standard library.  The class (just a function) must do one thing well, the `Vector` class stores a number of values of some type and provides constant-time random-access to the elements, it doesn't sort elements (that what `std::sort` algorithm is for), it does not search for elements (that what `std::find` and `std::find_if` algorithms are for), it does nit provide elementwise arithmetic operations (oops, there is no `std::zip` to combine several sequences into one), etc.

Comment: Thank you. I was think of using template<int width> as you suggested however I wasn't sure how to write operator<< for a generic FixedWidthDouble. Could you please show how this is done?

Comment: Thank you again. Could you expand a little on why you prefer not to make such methods a member? I come from a Java background where everything belongs to a class so I always get a strange feeling when I define a global function. Could you give some advice on when global functions are the 'right' thing to do in C++? Perhaps global functions are somewhat like static member functions in Java?